# Styling numbers of lists with css

Tags: html, css

How can I style the numbers on the list?
I made an ordered list and I want to style the numbers
To delete the dots
And Change color and background color

Comment: If you already have the knowledge on the html part, i suggest checking this [w3schools CSS Styling Lists](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp) i think it covers your needs.

Comment: CSS counter is also an option : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters  It also can be applied to any HTML structure/elements aside lists

Answer (score -1):

Here is a basic sample of what you are asking for:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: red;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It's about the dots also ;)

Comment: The dots on the numbers... that makes more sense. I thought OP mistakenly meant they made a `ul` or something